# PHP reading variable as class and attempting to autoload it

Tags: php, class, object, autoload

I have the following code in my class.
    `$pm->new_route_waypoints = array ();
    if($pm->assumed_type == 'O') {
    $pm->new_route_start = $pm->addressStart;
    $pm->new_route_end = $pm->addressEnd;
    $pm->new_route_waypoints [] = $this->_record->addressStart;
    $pm->new_route_waypoints [] = $this->_record->addressEnd;
    $pm->offer_distance = $pm->totalDistance;
    $pm->offer_duration = $pm->totalDuration;
    }
    else {
    $pm->new_route_start = $this->_record->addressStart;
    $pm->new_route_end = $this->_record->addressEnd;
    $pm->new_route_waypoints [] = $pm->addressStart;
    $pm->new_route_waypoints [] = $pm->addressEnd;
    $pm->offer_distance = $this->_record->totalDistance;
    $pm->offer_duration = $this->_record->totalDuration;
   }`

When this line `$pm->new_route_waypoints [] = $pm->addressStart;` runs it reads $pm->addressStart as a class and the autoloader tries to load it.  Specifically it reads the variable "123 Main St, Wilson, WY 83014, USA" and then gives this error:

> Warning: include_once(/Sites/website/classes/class.123 Main St, Wilson, WY 83014, USA.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Sites/website/testbed_db/startsession.php on line 11

Interestingly it does not throw the same error on the next line of code `$pm->new_route_waypoints [] = $pm->addressEnd;` which has the exact same type of value (an address) as the first line which causes the error.

I changed my autoloader to do an include_once instead of a require_once so it does not break my code, but I have been unable to figure out why I am getting this error.  I don't think it has anything to do with my autoloader code as I have tried substituting just using the __autoload function but Here is the code just in case:

```
define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
function __autoload_libraries($class_name) 
{
    include_once ROOT."classes/class.".$class_name.".php";
}

spl_autoload_register('__autoload_libraries');
```

Let me know if you need more in order to give me some ideas.

Thanks,

Matthew

Comment: Does your `$pm` class have any magic functions like `__get()` or `__set()` that might kick in and trigger the autoloader?

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for the reply.  $pm has no magic functions.  It is simply a stdClass I created.

Comment: Can you show us a var_dump of the `$pm` object before the line causing the error?